# Принадлежит ли точка области? ( картинка ниже, границы включены) Даны 2 действительных числа, вывести принадлежат ли они области

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import math

def IsPointInArea(x, y):
    qst1 = (y >= 2 * x + 2 and y >= -1 * x and math.sqrt(abs((x + 1)) ** 2 + abs((y - 1)) ** 2) <= 2)
# проверка Y >= f(x) 2x + 2 and -x и принадлежит ли кругу
    qst2 = (y <= 2 * x + 2 and y <= -1 * x and not (math.sqrt(abs((x + 1)) ** 2 + abs((y - 1)) ** 2) <= 2))
# проверека Y <= f(x) 2x + 2 and -x и not принадлежит кругу
    return qst1 or qst2

x = float(input())
y = float(input())
if IsPointInArea(x, y):
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Comment: 85/86 тестов проходит, я не знаю, что не предусмотрел

Comment: Вынесите в отдельные функции проверки "выше линии 1", "выше линии 2", "внутри круга". Тогда в итоге условие можно будет записать "(выше линии 1 и выше линии 2 и внутри круга) ИЛИ (не выше линии1 и не выше линии2 и не внутри круга)". Ну единственно с включением границ придется подумать, возможно по паре функций сделать для выше/ниже, внутри/снаружи

Comment: Спасибо, думал как сократить эту портянку, а то глаза режет

Comment: Решение зашло,  спасибо большое. ( Мне кажется я недосмотрел случай, когда точка на границе круга.)

Answer (score 0):

А так? Лишнее убрал, и условие для круга во втором было не точное (в вашем варианте `< 2` можно сделать)

```
qst1 = (y >= 2 * x + 2 and y >= -1 * x and (x + 1) ** 2 + (y - 1) ** 2 <= 4)
qst2 = (y <= 2 * x + 2 and y <= -1 * x and (x + 1) ** 2 + (y - 1) ** 2 >= 4)
```

Comment: @Shamekon Это уже второй ваш вопрос, на который я ответил, и ни один ответ не принят.